# CSS3 height:100% and flexible boxes creating unexpected behaviour

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a scrollbar-less page using CSS3 box-flex. Here's what I have:

```
<html>
<body style="height:100%;display:-webkit-box;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;"> <!-- height is 1000px -->
<div style="height:100px;">test</div>
<div style="-webkit-box-flex:1.0;">
  <div style="height:100%;">test</div> <!-- expected this to be 900px, but it's 1000px -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I make the child div fill up the rest of the page without using Javascript? (in this case, it's 900px).

P.S. I have Javascript resizing for browsers without CSS3 support.

Edit:
P.P.S: The child div is actually an iframe in my code, and box-flex doesn't seem to work on iframes.

Answer (score 1):

The height of the child div is determined by it's content: http://jsfiddle.net/yNQDK/

In this case One line of text